# Salesforce Bulk API - (Unable to update column ome_Contract__C for object "OME_Contract_Target__C" )

Tags: python, salesforce, bulk, veeva

I'm trying to update records for OME_Contract_Target__C in salesforce using sf.bulk.ome_contract_target__C and and it is throwing the below error

```
'errors': [{'statusCode': 'INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE',
    'message': 'Unable to create/update fields: OME_Contract__c. Please check the security settings of this field and verify that it is read/write for your profile or permission set.',
    'fields': ['OME_Contract__c']}]}]
```

This issue is happening only for OME_Contract__c column. Other columns are getting updated without any issues. Any suggestions to resolve this will be helpful.m

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Does the user that is performing the update (the one that is being used for authenticating the request) have edit permissions on that field ('OME_Contract__c')?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to identify which profile that the user is using.

Then go to the object manager and look for that object and field. View the field level security for that specific field.

make sure the profile of that user having a write access to that field.